# Integral representation of Kronecker delta

Tags: integration, kronecker-delta

I have seen this expression:

$$
\frac{1}{V}\int_Ve^{\pm i(\vec{n}-\vec{m})\cdot\vec{x}}d^3r=\delta_{\vec{n},\vec{m}}
$$

How can I prove it? Intuitively it seems right, but I would like to do it rigorously.

Comment: The first question is: what's the relationship between $\vec x$ and $r$? Then, are there some constraints about the $V$?

Comment: @Andrei Ok, maybe I should have written $\vec{r}$ and $dV$. The idea is that I am integrating in all volume V (no constraints) the vector $\vec{x}$.

Comment: The issue is that I can find a volume where that relationship is not correct

Comment: Mmm... ok, then I guess we can assume that the volume $V$ is a sphere of radius $R$.

Comment: You need to add one more thing, you need to take the limit $R\to \infty$

Comment: And why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\vec n=\vec m$, the integrand is $1$, so $$\frac 1V\int d^3r=\frac1V V=1$$
Let's do the integral in spherical coordinates for $\vec n\ne\vec m$, such that the $\theta$ angle is measured with respect to $\vec n -\vec m$. Then $$I=\frac1V\int_0^Rr^2dr\int_0^\pi\sin\theta d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi e^{i(\vec n-\vec m)\vec r}$$
In the exponent, let's use $|\vec n-\vec m|=a$. Then the exponent is $iar\cos\theta$. Note that $V=\frac 43 \pi R^3$, and the integral over $\phi$ is $2\pi$. Then $$I=\frac{3}{4\pi R^3}2\pi\int_0^R r^2dr\int_0^\pi\sin\theta d\theta e^{iar\cos\theta}$$
Change of variable $x=iar\cos\theta$. Then $dx=-iar\sin\theta d\theta$. When $\theta=0$ you have $x=iar$, and for $\theta=\pi$ you have $x=-iar$. Then $$I=\frac{3}{2R^3}\int_0^Rr^2dr\int_{iar}^{-iar}e^xdx\frac{1}{-iar}\\=\frac{3}{2R^3}\int_0^Rr^2dr\frac 1{iar}(e^{iar}-e^{-iar})\\=\frac{3}{2R^3}\int_0^Rr^2dr\frac 1{ar}2\sin(ar)$$
You can still see that in the limit $a=0$, which is $\vec n=\vec m$, $\frac{\sin(ar)}{ar}=1$, so $I=1$. If $a\ne 1$, change variable of integration $y=ar$, $dy=adr$, and the upper limit is now $Ra$:$$I=\frac3{R^3a^3}\int_0^{Ra}y\sin y dy$$
You can see that if $R$ is finite, the value of the integral might not be $0$. But you always have $-1\le\sin 1\le y$, so $$|I|\le \frac{3}{R^3a^3}\int_0^{Ra}y dy=\frac{3}{R^3a^3}\frac{R^2a^2}2$$
In the limit $R\to \infty$, with $\vec n\ne \vec m$, you get $I=0$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed proof! I was expecting that the relation would be valid for any volume, but following all your steps, I agree that only when $R\rightarrow\infty$ it holds.

Comment: Just a minor detail. I think in the last step you wanted to write $-1\leq\sin y\leq+1$ instead of $-1\leq\sin1\leq y$, right?

Comment: Yes. my mistake

Comment: Do you think there would be any difference if I consider the volume of a cube instead of a sphere?

Comment: No. You will have the same problem. Try to integrate the sine function on a given interval, then divide by the length of the interval. Unless the interval is multiple of $2\pi$, the integral is non-zero

Comment: Ok, I agree... I will add a little bit of context so you understand the motivation of my previous question. In a book they use this integral when dealing with the second quantized Dirac field operator. The argument is that it is "often advantageous and simplifies calculations if one considers second quantized fields in a finite volume". Values of the wave vector $\vec{q}$ are limited to the discrete values $q_x=\frac{2\pi}{L_x}n_x$, $q_y=\frac{2\pi}{L_y}n_y$ and $q_z=\frac{2\pi}{L_z}n_z$ (with $n_x$, $n_y$ and $n_z$ integers).

Comment: If the momentum is quantized as you imply, then the difference is also quantized, and then the box makes sense (the limits are multiple of $2\pi$). Then you don't need to go to infinitely large box.